# xchar = self.Reflector(xchar) TypeError: 'str' object is not callable. I scanned most of the answers, but here I am

Tags: python, string

I am have a problem with strings. To my eyes, this issue isn't any of the usually suspects. I don't understand why xchar = self.Reflector(xchar) is flagged when the two call before was ok.

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/.../Encrypt.py", 
line 35, in <module> Cipher = machine.Process_Message(Message,
replace_char=replaceVal)
File "/Users/.../EGdevice.py", line 104, in Process_Message code = self.Encode(char)
File "/Users/.../EGdevice.py", line 136, in Encode
xchar = self.Reflector(xchar)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
dennis@MBP2021 enigma %
```

The code snippets

```
def Encode(self, char):

    # Run charactor through the process
    logging.info(f'Original char: {char}')

    xchar = self.Plug_Board(char)
    logging.info(f'Recived Plugboard char: {xchar}')

    self.Rotate_Rotors()

    xchar = self.Thru_Roters_Forward(xchar)
    logging.info(f'Recive Forword Rotor char: {xchar}')

    xchar = self.Reflector(xchar)
    logging.info(f'Recived Relector char: {xchar}')

    xchar = self.Thru_Roters_Backword(xchar)
    logging.info(f'Recive Backward Rotor char: {xchar}')

    xchar = self.Plug_Board(xchar)
    logging.info(f'Last Plugboard char: {xchar}')

    return str(xchar)

def Thru_Roters_Forward(self, char):
    # Run thru the rotors from right to left.
    for x in reversed(range(self.rotorCount)):
        pos = int(self.rotorDetails[x][1])
        xchar = str(self.rotorDetails[x][3][pos][0])
    logging.info(f'Input: {char} Returned: {xchar}')
    return str(xchar)

def Reflector(self, char):
    xchar = self.Reflector[(ord(char) - 65) % 26]
    logging.info(f'Input: {char} Returned: {xchar}')
    return str(xchar)
```

And the logger output

```
2023.03.15 19:48:30|INFO|
>> FNC: Process_Message()
   MSG: Input data: This is the day the Lord has made. Be glad and rejoice.

2023.03.15 19:48:30|INFO|
>> FNC: Encode()
   MSG: Original char: T

2023.03.15 19:48:30|INFO|
>> FNC: Plug_Board()
   MSG: Input: T Returned: M

2023.03.15 19:48:30|INFO| 
>> FNC: Encode()
   MSG: Recived Plugboard char: M

2023.03.15 19:48:30|INFO|
>> FNC: Thru_Roters_Forward()
   MSG: Input: M Returned: K

2023.03.15 19:48:30|INFO|
>> FNC: Encode()
   MSG: Recive Rotor char: K
```

I scanned stack overflow and checked if I'm doing the print(str(str)) and the various forms of this issue. I tried to make the return char (a string) as a string: return str(xchar) I'm at a lost as the log shows it is a string.

Comment: Hint: the object being called, and which is not callable, is not `xchar`,  it is `self.Reflector`.

Comment: Thanks  Ture Pålsson, that helped. The reflector name was the same as the function name. 